# Adding Icon JLabel icon to the JTabbed Pane side

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtabbedpane, imageicon

I am trying to insert an icon via JLabel to the left side of my Jtabbed pane bar..but problem is what ever i insert at the left of my widnow it makes it a new tabe pane..How to insert icon showing in image..?[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - hot-link to an icon or generate an image in code.

Comment: i am using net beans so putting net beans auto generated code here, i do't think is a good idea.

Comment: Using Netbeans when you don't know how to program Java or override the defaults of your IDE is also not a good idea.  Voting to close.

Comment: i am a bit good at swing for time saving,i preffered net beans over coding..and i have changed many look and feels via coding in my application so it's not a big problem for me.

Comment: Good for you, and good luck with it.

Comment: I agree with you there are a lot of problems in selecting net beans and i learnt my lesson that's why will never go for it...but for this project i can not go back to drawing board and start coding.

Answer (score 1):

- use `JSplitPane` with one `JPanel` (left side) and `CardLayout` with `JTabbedPanes` (for `CENTER area`)
- put `JToggleButtons` with `Icons`  (left `JPanel`)
- put `JTabbedPanes` by using  `CardLayout` (`CENTER JFrames area`)
- use proper `Borders` for nicer output to the screen